# Sum answer not displaying

Tags: javascript

I have a program that I am currently trying to total.

The program is to have 10 numbers add into each text box and when the user hits the Sum button the program runs through the Add function and returns the total after the words 'Sum: '. The pages are linked with `<script src="functions.js"></script>` below the title tags.

Below are both pages.

```js
function Add() {
  var add_entries = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    var textentry = "Text" + i;
    var x = Number(document.getElementById(textentry).value);
    add_entries += x;
  }
  console.log(add_entries);
  document.getElementById("Sum: ").innerHTML = add_entries;

}
```

```html
Enter student test scores for all text boxes
<br>
<br>
<div>Blank responses will be treated as zeros.</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>Susan: <input id="Text1" type="text" /></div>
<div>Harry: <input id="Text2" type="text" /></div>
<div>Joe: <input id="Text3" type="text" /></div>
<div>Bill: <input id="Text4" type="text" /></div>
<div>Mary: <input id="Text5" type="text" /></div>
<div>Ken: <input id="Text6" type="text" /></div>
<div>Paul: <input id="Text7" type="text" /></div>
<div>John: <input id="Text8" type="text" /></div>
<div>Nora: <input id="Text9" type="text" /></div>
<div>Cindy: <input id="Text10" type="text" /></div>
<input id="Sum" type="button" value="Sum" onclick="Add()" />
<input id="Avg" type="button" value="Average" onclick="Avg()" />
<input id="High" type="button" value="Highest" onclick="Max()" />
<input id="Low" type="button" value="Lowest" onclick="Min()" />
<div>Sum: </div>
<div>Average: </div>
<div>Highest: </div>
<div>Lowest: </div>
```

Comment: use `parseInt` instead of `Number`

Comment: I tried, but nothing happens. I think the numbers are being added but the total is not being displayed after the div Sum:

Comment: 1. `i<=10` 2. give the div an ID `<div>Sum: <span id="result"></span></div>` and do `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add_entries;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("Sum: ").innerHTML = add_entries;`

That's not a valid id. Give your div an id and use that.

```
<div id="mySum">Sum: </div>
document.getElementById("mySum").innerHTML = add_entries;
```

If you want to retain the "Sum:" you can use a span.

```
<div>Sum: <span id="mySum"></span></div>
document.getElementById("mySum").innerHTML = add_entries;
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)` 11 needs to be changed to 10 because you dont have `Text11`

`document.getElementById("Sum: ").innerHTML = add_entries;` ID is not correct

if you want the output set to your `sum` div you need to set an ID on it and put the id in `document.getElementById(HERE)`

EDIT Answer:

change this line

```js
document.getElementById("Sum: ").innerHTML = add_entries;
```

to

```js
document.getElementById("sumDiv").innerHTML = 'Sum: ' + add_entries;
```

and then add an ID to your div were you want the output to be

Like this `<div id="sumDiv">Sum: </div>`

Comment: how do I fix the ID I want the sum that has been computed to appear after Sum: (answer here) I currently have this sum in a div

Comment: `<div id="result">Sum: </div>`  ---- `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add_entries;`

Comment: @user14391552 
change this line 
 ```document.getElementById("Sum: ").innerHTML = add_entries; ```

to

```document.getElementById("sumDiv").innerHTML = 'Sum: ' + add_entries; ```

and change your div to   ``` <div id="sumDiv">Sum: </div> ```

Answer (score 0):

The for statement goes one step too far, if you check the console you will see an error stating something like, "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null", thats because its checking id="Text11"
change:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
```

to:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

and maybe even check that document.getElementById(textentry) doesn't return null before using it.
And of course, "use parseInt instead of Number" as Ameer said, or use a plus sign :/

```
 +(document.getElementById(textentry).value);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your for loop you're reaching 11, I can only see 10 text inputs in your HTML.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.